# Find ID of paragraph based on the text match

Tags: jquery

How can I get the ID of a paragraph when I pass text "Selection List" or "Deletion List".

```
"<p id="section_548540600_title" class="CollapseExpand CollapseExpand_active" title="Collapse / Expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Selection List</a></p>"

"<p id="section_362548963_title" class="CollapseExpand CollapseExpand_active" title="Collapse / Expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Deletion List</a></p>"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to match elements based on their text content:

```
// Where `someString` is "Selection List" or "Deletion List":
var id = $("p:contains('" + someString + "')").attr("id");
```

---

**Update**

Note that the above approach assumes you only have a single element containing each string. If there are other elements containing the same strings, you may need a different approach to ensure the element contains *only* that string:

```
var id = $("p").filter(function () {
             return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Test";
         }).attr("id");
```

Comment: Ha, this isn't what I answered at all, but I can totally see how this could be what he's asking. +1

Comment: @DavidHedlund - I saw your answer just before I posted this and wondered whether I had got the question wrong, but looks like most people are interpreting it the way I did. It's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a HTML string to jQuery will give you the DOM representation of that string, which you can then manipulate just like you normally manipulate any nodes actually present in the DOM. In your case:

```
$(htmlString).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, clicking the paragraph, you can do like this :

HTML : (added class to the anchor tag)

```
      "<p id="section_548540600_title" class="CollapseExpand CollapseExpand_active" title="Collapse / Expand"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class='myclass'>Selection List</a></p>"
```

JS :

```
     $(".myclass").on({

       click : function(e){
          req_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");

        }
     });
```

Comment: Please stop using `.live()`. It's been deprecated for ages now. Use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.